# Rewrite to strip end off URLs with a specific end path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know this should be simple, but I cant get it.

How can I strip off update/ from any and all URLs that end with update/

In other words, www.domain.com/news/stuff/update/ should rewrite to  www.domain.com/news/stuff/

or

```
www.domain.com/update/ -> www.domain.com/

www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/update/ -> www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/
```

This doesnt work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} update/$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)update/ $1
```

Oh, and I need it to NOT be a L (last rule) since there will be additional URL processing after this. Just need to get rid of the update/ before the other rules.

Thanks

Comment: You need to use `R` flag to redirect if you want to remove it from the URL `RewriteRule ^(.*)update/ $1 [R=301,L]` Don't worry a redirect causes the rules to be read again even with L

Comment: Thanks PJ! The R flag did the trick <smh>